# Tensorflow React - Error: modelWeightsID must be a number or number array when import

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo, tensorflow.js

So I've opened an issue on github (https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/7001) about this, but not heard anything as of yet so trying here again.

I've got an react native expo application which I have imported my model and weights as such:

```
import modelJSON from '../../../assets/model/model.json'
import modelWeights from '../../../assets/model/group1-shard.bin'
```

however when I then initialise the model, like so:

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
                bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights),
            ).catch((error: Error) => {
                log(400, error)
            })
```

I get the following error:

```
react-native-logs.fx.ts:22 
        
       Warn: Error: modelWeightsID must be a number or number array.
Have you wrapped yor asset paths in a require() statements?
    at bundleResourceIO (bundle_resource_io.ts:178:1)
    at image-card.tsx:103:1
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong as I've tried requiring the weights as well to the same result.

The full gist is here: https://gist.github.com/TGTGamer/211b6969bf5488dd28973cd6e71ee87c

The packages used are here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs & https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have used this format when importing the files:

```js
const modelJson = require('../../../assets/model/model.json');
const modelWeights= require('../../../assets/model/group1-shard.bin');

const loadModel = async () => {
   const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights));
   return model;
}
```

Comment: As stated in the original message, I have tried requiring the files as well and that hasn't solved the issue. Could you take another look?

Comment: I have met different issues by using tfjs on React native CLI generated project and decided to convert everything in an Expo one and now it seems to work smoothly.

Comment: Oh, could you update your answer with the steps you took to resolve it to help me understand?

Comment: Not specifically to this issue, some conflicts occur even in the native files of the android folder, so I had to migrate the RN-CLI project to the Expo one. And this by creating a fresh Expo project and moving my files one by one (but remember to make a backup)

Comment: thanks for the advice, unfortunately for me, I'm experiencing this in an expo managed project :) - Might have to keep trying new things